# How to swap two XML elements through DOM Parser/Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I have an XML doc-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?> 
<Companies>
<company id="ABHISHEK">
    <staff id="1">
        <firstname>yong</firstname>
        <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
        <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
        <salary>100000</salary>
    </staff>
</company>
<company id="RAHUL">
    <staff id="2">
        <firstname>yong</firstname>
        <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
        <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
        <salary>100000</salary>
    </staff>
</company>
</Companies>
```

Now I want to swap the category ABHISHEK and RAHUL so that in xml , Compay with ID RAHUL comes first then ABHISHEK.
Is there any existing API to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, have a look at the `org.w3c.dom` package and the `Node` interface.

If the order of <company> elements depend on some sort order, perhaps XSLT is a better alternative.

Comment: RootElement.insertBefore(secondChild, parentChild); this logic worked